# Looping through all files in a folder (encountering run time error '-2147221080 (800401a8)')

Tags: vba, loops, runtime-error

I am running a code that aims to pull in data from all workbooks within a specific folder. I have written the code for the loop separate from the code for the pulling in of data.

```
Sub FixedIncomeLoop()

    Dim file            As Variant
    Dim wb1             As Workbook
    Dim wb2             As Workbook
    Dim folderpath      As String
    Dim ws              As Worksheet
    Dim ws2             As Worksheet

    Set wb1 = ActiveWorkbook
    Set ws = ActiveSheet

    folderpath = "C:\Users\Wei Hong\Documents\Trade Tickets\"

    file = Dir(folderpath)

    While (file <> "")
        Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(file)
        Set ws2 = wb2.Worksheets("Trade Ticket")
        Call FixedIncome(wb1, ws, ws2)
        wb2.Close SaveChanges:=False
        Set wb2 = Nothing
    Wend

End Sub


Private Sub FixedIncome(wb1 As Workbook, ws As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet)

    Dim ws3 As Worksheet

    Set ws3 = wb1.Worksheets("Constants")  <-- facing error

    ws.Activate

...
End Sub
```

I am facing the runtime error above. Not sure why!

Comment: I see to potential bugs in your code 1) folderpath is not included in your open instruction Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(folder path & file) 2) you should restrict the dir to excel file file = Dir(folderpath & "\*.xls*"). however this does not explain the message you get.

Comment: i see 2 potentital bugs ...

Comment: can the folder contain non excel sheets?

Comment: thanks for the responses guys. I managed to resolve the issue by setting ws3 in my FixedIncomeLoop Sub instead, and then passing ws3 through into FixedIncome Sub when I call it. I left the rest of the code within FixedIncome Sub untouched, and it is able to reference wb1, ws, ws2, and ws3 in FixedIncome Sub accordingly. So... a workaround, but still not sure what caused the issue exactly